# Function is Compiled but in the time of execution Only return first letter of the string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

/* Write a function to insert the string in a table which will display the character of string If You enter Sameer then output will be

s

a

m

e

e

r

*/

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(c in varchar2)
                  return varchar2
is
a number := 0;
b varchar2(20);
var_len number := length(c);
begin
     loop
         a := a + 1;
        select SUBSTR(c, a,1) into b from dual;
           EXIT when  a <= var_len;
           dbms_output.put_line(b);

    END LOOP;
               return b;
END;

SELECT f1('Sameer') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: `a <= var_len` is wrong - that will exit first time through. I think you just meant `=`? You might want that check *after* the `put_line` though, and it's unclear what you should return (or why it would be a function rather than a procedure).

Comment: Same thing happen, Only first letter shown

Answer (score 0):

```sql
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(c in varchar2)
                  return varchar2
is
mRet VarChar2(50) := '';
begin
     FOR i in 1..Length(c) LOOP
        mRet := mRet || SubStr(c, i, 1) || Chr(10);
    END LOOP;
    return RTRIM(mRet, Chr(10));
END;

SELECT f1('Sameer') FROM DUAL;
--  
--  R e s u l t
--      
--  F1('SAMEER')
--  ------------
--  S           
--  a           
--  m           
--  e          
--  e          
--  r
```

Comment: I am not understood why you give   mRet VarChar2(50) := '';

Comment: why you did this   mRet := mRet

Comment: Oh, it is just a sample function and I defined it at the size of 50. You can do whatever you want and define it differently, offcourse. The function reads the given string and after every character adds a new line (char(10)) so you culd have a returned value as shown in the result. I also removed the trailing new line character using RTRIM function. As in your question an insert of this result into some table was mentioned - this result is suitaable for such a task if needed. Regards...

Comment: Variable mRet was declared as an empty string ( '' ) so I can later add the leters and new line characters in the for loop. This is just a starting value which is not null, as null could act strangely in some actions. It is just my habbit to give initial value to variables where possible.

Comment: But the output is coming in a single line when click on pencil icon then it comes in different line but this is not my requirement, my requirement is it comes with different character but here you only create new line.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what you need. This is the way to put every leter in new line. If you insert it in the table and select it - it wil be as it is now. If you want every letter in new record of the table then you should just put an insert command within for loop  and put every letter in a new record. For loop gives you individual letters using i as a counter. So the same code structure can do the job differently. This is the structure and you can do whatever you want with individual letters.

Comment: Inside FOOR LOOP Instead of
mRet := mRet || SubStr(c, i, 1) || Chr(10);
Put this
Insert into YourtableName (YourColumnName) Values(SubStr(c, i, 1));
And after END LOOP put theese two commands:    
Commit;
Return 'OK - Commited';
If that is what you need then consider to change the function into procedure, though it can stay as it is. 
And take care of other columns of the table you are inserting in..so you could preserve the sequencial order...

Answer (score 0):

Your code (when fixed, as Alex suggested), *displays* desired output (all letters in separate rows), but function *returns* only the last letter:

```
SQL> set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(c in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    a number := 0;
  5    b varchar2(20);
  6    var_len number := length(c);
  7  begin
  8    loop
  9       a := a + 1;
 10       select SUBSTR(c, a,1) into b from dual;
 11       dbms_output.put_line(b);
 12       EXIT when  a = var_len;
 13    END LOOP;
 14    return b;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT f1('Sameer') FROM DUAL;

F1('SAMEER')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
r           --> this is what function returns

S           --> this is result
a           --> of the
m           --> DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
e
e
r
SQL>
```

---

Though, that's not what you wanted - you want to *return* such an output. One option is to concatenate all `b` values with the line feed character (`chr(10)`):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(c in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    a number := 0;
  5    b varchar2(20);
  6    var_len number := length(c);
  7  begin
  8    loop
  9       a := a + 1;`enter code here`
 10       b := b || SUBSTR(c, a,1) || chr(10);
 11       EXIT when  a = var_len;
 12    END LOOP;
 13    return b;
 14  END;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT f1('Sameer') FROM DUAL;

F1('SAMEER')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S           --> this is return value, a "single" value, not 
a           --> separate letters, each in its own row
m
e
e
r


SQL>
```

---

If you run it in SQL Developer, you won't see it properly unless you double click the result (which is the "Sameer") word, then click the pencil button and here's your result.

[image]

---

Also, consider somewhat simpler option:

```
SQL> create or replace function f1 (c in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return regexp_replace(c, '(.)', '\1' ||chr(10));
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT f1('Sameer') FROM DUAL;

F1('SAMEER')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S
a
m
e
e
r


SQL>
```